# Java - Treemap Serialization error using RMI

Tags: java, serialization, server, rmi, treemap

I'm working on a project using a java server and a java client, linked via RMI. All seems to work fine except when I try to return a TreeMap from the server to client. I created the following method in my Server :

```
public TreeMap<Integer,Joueur> getJoueurs() throws RemoteException 
{
    return(this.joueurs);

}
```

With the variable joueurs being created before :

```
private TreeMap<Integer,Joueur> joueurs;
```

And I created a class defining the object Joueur().

Then added the method to the Interface :

```
TreeMap<Integer,Joueur> getJoueurs() throws RemoteException;
```

But when I try to use it in my client via the previous method :

```
joueurs = monopolyInterface.getJoueurs();
```

I get the following error :

```
java.rmi.UnmarshalException: error unmarshalling return; nested exception is: 
java.io.WriteAbortedException: writing aborted; java.io.NotSerializableException: monopoly.Joueur
at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.invoke(UnicastRef.java:193)
at java.rmi.server.RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.invokeRemoteMethod(RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.java:227)
at java.rmi.server.RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.java:179)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy0.getJoueurs(Unknown Source)
at monopoly.FenetreConnexion.actionPerformed(FenetreConnexion.java:127)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2348)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6535)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6300)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2236)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4891)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2294)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4713)
...
```

So I thought that TreeMaps were serializable and my variable "joueurs" is set to be a TreeMap and exists even in the client. 
What am I doing wrong ?

Thanks for your answers !

Comment: Have your Joueur (and its attributes) class implement Serializable interface.

Comment: THANKS ! @AmitParashar